# How to find out the username and password for mysql database

Tags: mysql, passwords

I've forgotten what I set as username and password for `mysql` database. How could I be able to find it out? I am using wamp server. I am a newbie in `mysql`.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Go to this file in: `WampFolder\apps\phpmyadmin[phpmyadmin version]\config.inc.php`

Usually wamp is in your main hard drive folder `C:\wamp\`

You will see something like:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'YOUR USER NAME IS HERE';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'AND YOU PASSWORD IS HERE';
```

Try using the password and username that you have on that file.

Comment: How do I get the password for admin having all permissions?

Comment: Can we change username and password there too?

Comment: My config.inc.php file is empty

Comment: @Fábio Antunes, Thanks a lot for the great answer, however in my case the username & password in phpMyAdmin/config.inc  are matching  the same in config.php, but i still have Error establishing a database connection!! Why is that please?

Comment: I suggest you post a new question with details of your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the user you are using in phpmyadmin has the necessary privileges, you can run this query to change the root password:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Ive executed the above querry now it gives following error..
#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: @aeonsleo: Check out the MySQL documentation for how to change the mysql root password if you have no access: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-windows

Comment: Password field has been changed now to authentication_string.

Answer (score 0):

If you forget your password for SQL plus 10g then follow the steps :

1. START
2. Type RUN in the search box
3. Type 'cnc' in the box captioned as OPEN and a black box will appear
   4.There will be some text already in the box. (C:\Users\admin>) Just beside that start typing 'sqlplus/nolog' press ENTER key
4. On the next line type 'conn sys/change_on_install as sysdba' (press ENTER)
   6.(in the next line after sql-> type) 'alter user scott account unlock' .
5. Now open your slpplus and type user name as 'scott' and password as 'tiger'.

If it asks your old password then type the one you have given while installing.

Answer (score -1):

In your local system right,

```
   go to this url : http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

   In this click mysql default db, after that browser user table to get existing username and password.
```

Comment: I saw the password but i think this is not the passwd i created. Its a long computer generated one, is that it?

Comment: that password only we used in projects, so use that one

Answer (score -1):

One of valid JDBC url is

```
jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wsmg?user=root&password=root
```

Answer (score -2):

There are two easy ways:

1. In your cpanel
   Go to cpanel/ softaculous/ wordpress, under the current installation, you will see the websites you have installed with the wordpress.
   Click the "edit detail" of the particular website and you will see your SQL database username and password.
2. In your server
   Access your FTP and view the wp-config.php

Comment: Note that a Sofaculous/Wordpress item is not available in all cPanel installations, so that method cannot be used by everyone. The second requires that you be using Wordpress, which the original question did not indicate. Also, they would not have to FTP to their server, since they're using WAMP on a local machine.

Answer (score -4):

Open **phpmyadmin**, go to database and corresponding table to find it out.

Comment: @James Goodwin: Yes, that's true, don't know whether he is storing in plain text or encrypting it.

Comment: The OP is referring to the password for the MYSQL user, not an ordinary password stored in a user created table. By default MySQL encrypts the password in the `mysql.user` table using the `PASSWORD()` function.