# Access denied for user 'testweb'@'localhost' drupal site configuration in localhost

Tags: php, drupal

I have setup a web site in the internet and I try to host it locally and test it.
Normally, in Drupal database connection can be configured from `settings.php` file which is located at: `\sites\default`.

Here is the code that set access:

```
$databases = array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'testweb',
      'username' => 'testweb',
      'password' => 'root',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
```

MySQL web user and database names are equal that is testweb.

Here is the error I get.

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'testweb'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of C:\wamp\www\testweb\includes\lock.inc).

Another thing I want to know that is whether Drupal store database connection strings in the database.

I have seen this problem in stackoverflow but it didn't continue to a right solution.

Comment: username\password\db incorrect

Comment: Did you imported the sql dump?

Comment: I had this same error, the user and host and password were correct. It was a rights issue in mysql so user needed the correct GRANTs to access the db otherwise got that lock_may_be_available() error in Drupal 7(.x.26)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a alternative solution for this that is I use default mysql user to connect the database

```
$databases = array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'testweb',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => '',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
```

This was helped me to solve my issue.
You can find the default user in following location if it is wamp server that you use.

```
C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.5.1
```

File is `config.inc.`

What I assumed is that the user I created for the testweb database doesn't reflect it is rights or it hasn't been created properly because I am very much sure about the username and password I gave and default user name and password works. This may not be a drupal issue.

Comment: Thanks, that does work but it still doesn't explain what triggers the error, or how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

your username or password or db name may be incorrect.

You can try connecting to your db with some mysql client or phpmyadmin and check if they correct, i'm sure one of them is not :)

you can easly create new users in phpmyadmin http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/user_management

Comment: can anybody tell why this answere is down voted?

Comment: @pottuamman don' t worry :) sometimes random downvotes around lol, and they without reasons at all :/

Comment: how to check password from phpadmin?

Comment: @pottuamman http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703996/how-to-find-out-the-username-and-password-for-mysql-database

Comment: that is defaul user, in my case I had created a separate users for each database via phpmyadmin panel. Do you know how to do get that  password?

Comment: @pottuamman first google result :D http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/user_management , anyway i do not use phpmyadmin i use a client for example Mysql Browser or SQLpro which are better then a web interface tool ;)