# #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, localhost, port, wamp

This might seem redundant but I was unable to find a correct solution.

I was unable to login to mysql using the mysql console.It is asking for a password and I have no clue what I actually entered.(Is there a way to get the password or change it?)
This is how my config.inc look.

When I try to open phpmyadmin I get this error(#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES))

```
<?php

/* Servers configuration */
$i = 0;

/* Server: localhost [1] */
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'prakash123';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

/* End of servers configuration */

$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en-utf-8';
$cfg['ServerDefault'] = 1;
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';


/* rajk - for blobstreaming */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_garbage_threshold'] = 50;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_repository_threshold'] = '32M';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_temp_blob_timeout'] = 600;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_temp_log_threshold'] = '32M';


?>
```

I have tried to uninstall( Plus Deleted all the related files)  WAMP and reinstall.It didn't help either.
While reinstalling WAMP server it is not asking for any username password stuff I don't know why.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to move away the database 'mysql' (which is where the credentials live) and see, if it is recreated on restart?

Comment: Look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703996/how-to-find-out-the-username-and-password-for-mysql-database

I'd say that 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'prakash123';
prakash123 is your password.

Comment: #2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server this is the new error I get when moved Mysql @Eugen Rieck

Comment: @helenbn I know prakash123 is my password but I was not able to open PHPMyadmin

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem was I have 2 instances of Mysql installed and I didn't know the password for both instances.Just check if port 80 is used by any of the programs.
This is what I did

1.Quit Skype because it was using port 80.(Please check if port 80 is used by any other program).

2.Search for Mysql services in task manager and stop it.

3.Now delete all the related mysql files.Make sure you delete all the files.

4.Reinstall

Answer (score 39):

I first changed the root password running mysql at a prompt with

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Update password:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root';
```

Edited line in the file `config.inc.php` with the new root password:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'MyNewPass'
```

Stop and re-start mysql service (in Windows: `mysql_stop.bat`/`mysql_start.bat`)

and got phpMyAdmin to work!

EDIT 2017: for MySQL≥5.7 use `authentication_string` in place of  `Password` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31122246/2314737)):

```
`UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root';
```

`

Comment: after doing this **kill** mysql process and start it again!

Comment: What should I do if `mysql -u root -p` requires a password, and anything you try results in the #1045 error?

Comment: @StanDerksen The password in my case of  `mysql -u root -p`  was the root password for the server.

Answer (score 5):

Well, there are many solutions already given above. If there are none of them works, maybe you should just try to reset your password again to 'root' as described [here](http://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/error-1045-phpmyadmin/), and then reopen `http://localhost/phpMyAdmin/` in other browser. At least this solution works for me.

Answer (score 2):

mysql.exe->Run as administrator or go to following path C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin and than right click on mysql.exe go to properties and than select tab as Compatibility and see the bottom of dialog box in **privilege level** and just check the Run this program as an administrator and then click apply ok.finished now you open success phpMyadmin. bye

Answer (score 2):

1. `mysql -u root -p`
2. `UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('mypass') WHERE User='root';`
3. Flush the privileges: `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
4. Exit by typing: `Exit`
5. Edited line in the file config.inc.php with the new root password: `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'mypass'`
6. **be succss**

Comment: UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('yourpassword') WHERE User='root'; if some one using the mysql5.7. the above update does not work in this version...

Answer (score 2):

Go to 'config.inc.php'. Write your password over here - `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] =''`

Answer (score 2):

This process is quite simple in correcting the the error. What is happening is a failure to connect to phpMyAdmin. In order to fix the problem you simply need to provide the correct password to the system phpMyAdmin configuration file located in apps\phpMyadmin\config.ini.php
1. the root should already be set as user
2. Insert the password between ' ' and that it.

If you still have problems then this means that the user name and /or the password need to be updated or inserted into the DB. to do this use the command line tool and do an update.

UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('Johnny59 or whatever you want to use') WHERE User='root';

Answer (score 2):

Go to `config.inc.php`, find `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']` and remove any password provided, i.e change `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'password';` with `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';`

Now you can launch *phpMyAdmin*

Selecting *Users* menu from *phpMyAdmin*, select the *root* user and click *Edit previlidges*.
Now scroll down to **Change Password** area, switch between **No Password** and **Password** to provide your new password.
that's it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error today. I had installed Djangostack and when I checked my task manager there were two instances of mysqld running. I checked one was for wamp server and the other was for django stack. I ended the one for django stack, restarted all services in wamp server and I was able to access phpmyadmin

Answer (score 2):

after installation i started wamp and i was asked for user and pass which were already set on default (user:admin pass: dots), and that was wrong with a message from your topic. Than, i just entered:

```
Username: root 
Password: (leave it empty)
```

and it worked for me!!

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to `C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin`
2. Edit the `config.inc.php` file
3. Replace `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';` by
   `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';`

For now on the `PHPMyAdmin` will ask you for your password, no more error.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.
In your config file

```
$cfg['Servers']['$i']['password'] = 'yourpassword';
```

In your mysql shell, login as root

```
mysql -u root
```

change your password or update if you've forgotten the old one

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('yourpassword') WHERE User='root';
```

stop and restart your mysql server from the xampp control panel. phpmyadmin can login to see your databases

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

if you see Password column field as 'No' for the 'root' user in `Users Overview` page of  phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1):

with MariaDb, above solutions doesn't works.

Use (exemple below with ubuntu 16.04 and mariadb-server Distrib 10.0.28):

```
    sudo mysql_secure_installation
    …
    Change the root password? [Y/n] 
    New password:
```

Answer (score 1):

For UNIX, try this. It worked for me:

1. connect MySQL use Navicat Premium with inital root/"password"
2. `UPDATE mysql.user
       SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('MyNewPass'), password_expired = 'N'
       WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost';
   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
3. restart MySQL

Comment: When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered similar mistakes, and later found that my password is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to go config.inc.php file then change the following instruction

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] ='';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] ='';
```

or

[image]

Comment: what is the path for that file?

Answer (score 0):

If you arrived here because you can't log into your phpMyAdmin, then try the root password from your Mysql instead of the password you put during phpMyAdmin installation.

Answer (score 0):

Just now I have this situation and I have tried this way which is very easy.

First stop your mysql service using this command:

```
service mysql stop
```

and then just again start your mysql service using this command

```
service mysql start
```

I hope it may help others... :)

Answer (score 0):

After I updated my MySql, I was getting the same error message.
It turned out that after installing a different version on MySql, inside the my.ini, the port was different. Previous MySql version had port 3306 but the new one have port 3308.
Check your MySql my.ini, if it is different use the port from .ini in your connection.

Answer (score 0):

```
php artisan serve
```

this command get the env contents for the first time and if you update .env file need to restart it.

in my case my username and dbname is valid and **php artisan migrate** worked

but need to cntrl+c , to cancel php artisan serve , and run it again

```
php artisan serve
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the name of *Environment Variable*

#### Case with me:

- I was using `sqlalchemy` in a `python-flask` project and got this issue.
- IDE used: **PyCharm**
- In my `config.py` file I had setup `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` as:

```py
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.getenv("DATABASE_URI")
```

#### Mistake I did (it was a silly mistake )

- While setting `evironment_variables` in PyCharm, I did:

```sh
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI=<my_db_uri>
```

#### Solution

- I changed the above to:

```sh
DATABASE_URI=<my_db_uri>
```

**Namaste**

Answer (score -1):

In the my.ini file in C:\xampp\mysql\bin, add the following line after the `[mysqld]` command under `#Mysql Server`:

```
skip-grant-tables
```

This should remove the error 1045.

Comment: Please add that this may only be a temporary solution until a proper password is set!

Answer (score -1):

if multiple myslq running on same port no 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6WYn.jpg)

Right click on wamp  and test port 3306
if its wampmysqld64  its correct else change port no and restart server