# Error 1045 in sql while exporting file

Tags: mysql, sql, database, export

```
SELECT name.id,
       name.full,
FROM   name 
INTO OUTFILE 'tmp/export.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

When I run this query, it return error

> 1045 - Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

What should I do to solve this problem?

Also is this part correct in above query?

> INTO OUTFILE 'tmp/export.csv'

Comment: Are you entering correct username and password?

Comment: check correct answer of link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16845715/1045-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes

Comment: where to enter username? I am on live server and already login

Comment: you are doing this query using php or directly in phpmyadmin panel?

Comment: @A-2A directly in phpmyadmin panel, will it work or not?