# PHP apache error: Access denied for user 'jobportal'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp, wampserver

I tried to access the index page of my website: index.php, via this link:
localhost:80/web/index.php. This brought me to a blank page on chrome that shows the error result:

> Warning: Declaration of SugarDateTime::setTime($hour, $minute, $sec = 0) should be compatible with DateTime::setTime($hour, $minute, $second = NULL, $microseconds = NULL) in C:\xampp\htdocs\uat\include\SugarDateTime.php on line 692
>   Could not connect to the database. Please refer to simplecrm.log for details.

I checked the "simplecrm.log" file, it showed me the error:

> Could not connect to DB server localhost as jobportal. port : Access denied for user 'jobportal'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I have scoured the internet for answers, especially:

- https://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/error-1045-phpmyadmin/
- [MySQL said: Documentation #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11096045/mysql-said-documentation-1045-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-usi)
- [#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16845715/1045-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes)

But these answers only show the root user, while my issue refers to the "jobportal" user. I did try the solutions given but I still can't solve this issue.

Here is the code in index.php:

```
include ('include/MVC/preDispatch.php');
$startTime = microtime(true);
require_once('include/entry.php');
ob_start();
require_once('include/MVC/SugarApp.php');
$app = new SugarApp();
$app->startSession();
$app->execute();
```

Comment: what os you're on and what stack you're using??

Comment: I'm using windows 7, and using xampp. I tried wampserver but it has the same error

Comment: Did you create a user account called `jobportal`? Did you give that new account access to the database you are using? Did you give that account the same password you are using in your code?

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes, already done that. This user isn't the root user. Do I have to edit anything in the config.inc.php file?

Comment: Not sure about XAMPP, but WAMPServer's phpMyAdmin throws a login screen that asks for a UserId and Password so you dont need to amend the `config.inc.php` file. You can use any valid UserId/Password pair to login to MySQL from phpMyAdmin.

Comment: It sounds like you have not created a `jobportal` user in MySQL or you are using a password in your code that does not match the password you set on the `jobportal` account.

Answer (score 1):

If you set your database password then write like

```
$db_name = 'dbname';
$db_pass = 'yourPasss';

Else 
$db_name = 'dbname';
$db_pass = ''; //empty
```

Comment: which file do I make these changes?

Comment: Errr `phpMyAdmin` does not have a password, its a PHP application. However a MySQl account does have a password

Comment: #Riggs  I know. but i think this would help to understand easily. 
#Denise in your database connection. Like... 
mysqli_connect('host', 'user', 'pass', 'dbName');

Answer (score 0):

Try granting all privilages on the database to user jobportal using the following SQL, like so:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON your_database.* TO 'jobportal'@'localhost' 
IDENTIFIED BY 'your_db_password';
```

After executing the above, execute the following:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It shows ' Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'jobportal'

Comment: Is jobportal the user or the database?