# How to create MySQL user with php script

Tags: php, mysql

So I managed to fix it myself, unsure how tho, this is my final code:

```
//create user 
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","******");
$crearuser="CREATE USER 'phpuser'@'localhost' identified by '******'";
if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
echo "It Works";
}
else
{
echo "Nope";
}
```

Like I said, im unsure of how I fixed it, but this and the grant part (not going to paste, so much code) are fully working, thank you all :)

Comment: Does your database have a password to access it?

Comment: Try using `mysqli_error()` inside the else block and see if you get any error

Comment: @korocota what you exactly get when you run your script?

Comment: @james i just get that Nope. Now that I added the mysqli_error show this:Field 'ssl_cipher' doesn't have a default value

Answer (score 0):

Just reference to it: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html

```
$createuser = "CREATE USER 'phpuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Script runs fine on my side. I think you have problem in connecting with database

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","******","mysql");
```

Because during the editing process you changed your password parameter 3 times. And you are not sure about your password.
Try to figure out your `mysqli_connect()` parameters.
This question will help you too..[How to find out the username and password for mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703996/how-to-find-out-the-username-and-password-for-mysql-database)

Comment: Im absolutely sure about that password, im running another app from the same db with no problems

Comment: @korocota okay then. echo your query and run it in wamp.

Comment: check your Host,User,Password in database. All three fields have same spelling their as well?

Comment: Just a tip: There is another way to work with users: Add a user table, then insert or update users as you want with Usernumber,  username etc.